# issue porting signal code from PyQt4 to PySide2

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, pyside2

the QtCore.QObject.connect in PySide2 is not working as it was in PyQt4. Signal ordering seams to be the issue.
Is it a known bug or a feature that is not supported in PySide2 ?
Any help will be appreciated, 
Thanks you, Eric

Working example: (sorry I couldn't make it shorter to demonstrate the issue)

Typically the output under PySide2 is complaining about signal and slot not being ordered.

Signals and slots in QMetaObject 'BaseEditor' are not ordered correctly, this may lead to issues.

1. Signal initFirstTimeDONE(object)
2. Slot aclick(object)
3. Signal optionChangeDONE(object)

---

```
import os
import sys
import types
from collections import namedtuple

try:
    from PySide2 import QtCore,QtWidgets,QtGui
    SINGLE_ARG = 'object'
except:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui 
    from PyQt4 import QtGui as QtWidgets
    SINGLE_ARG = 'PyQt_PyObject'

######################################################################  
class baseSig(object):
    """ helper mixing for signal name and signature """
    @property
    def asTuple(self):
        return self.name,self.arg

class signalInfoT(namedtuple("signalInfo", 
                         "name arg signature"),baseSig):
    __slots__ = ()

def signalInfo(name, arg, signature=None):
    if signature == None:
        return signalInfoT(name,arg,"%s(%s)" % (name,arg))
    else:
        return signalInfoT(name,arg,signature)


# declare 2 signalInfo
OPTION = signalInfo('optionChange',SINGLE_ARG)
INITF = signalInfo('initFirstTime',SINGLE_ARG)


######################################################################
class Msg(object):
    """ Signal argument type """
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a


######################################################################
class BaseEditor(QtCore.QObject):
    """ object that centralized all the signal declaration (as a hub)
        and in which widget can register connection (request_connect)
    """
    def __init__(self,**args):
        super(BaseEditor,self).__init__()
        self._Assign = {}
        self.declare_signalT(INITF.asTuple, self.initFirst, SINGLE_ARG)
        self.declare_signalT(OPTION.asTuple, self.aclick, SINGLE_ARG)

    def declare_signalT(self,sig,functMethod,cbSignature=""):
        self.declare_signal(sig[0],sig[1],functMethod,cbSignature)

    def declare_signal(self,sName,sSignature,functMethod,cbSignature=""):

        self._Assign[sName] = {
                "signal":QtCore.SIGNAL("%s(%s)" % (sName,sSignature)),
                "methodR": functMethod,
                "signalDone": QtCore.SIGNAL("%sDONE(%s)" % (sName,
                                                        cbSignature))
                }

    def request_connect(self,emitter,sName,canEmit,callerCB = None):
        """Main method to register signal"""

        if canEmit:
            x = self.connect(emitter,self._Assign[sName]["signal"],self._Assign[sName]["methodR"])
        if callerCB != None:
            x = emitter.connect(self,self._Assign[sName]["signalDone"],callerCB)

    def initFirst(self, msg):
        self.emit(self._Assign[INITF.name]["signalDone"],msg)
    def aclick(self,msg):
        print "BaseEditor: this is not called", msg
        self.emit(self._Assign[OPTION.name]["signalDone"],msg)

######################################################################
class AWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent,**argv):
        super(AWidget,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName("ll%s" % id(self))
        verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Hey")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        editor = argv.get('editor')
        editor.request_connect(self, INITF.name, False, self.init_first)
        editor.request_connect(self, OPTION.name, True,self.ahaha)

    def init_first(self,msg):
        self.lineEdit.setText("%s" % msg.a)

    def on_click(self):
        msg = Msg(3)
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL(OPTION.signature),msg)

    def ahaha(self,msg):
        print "ahaha: this is never called with Qt5", msg
        self.lineEdit.setText("%s" % msg.a)

#####################################################################
class ShotInfoMain(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent,**argv):
        super(ShotInfoMain, self).__init__(parent)
        verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setObjectName("shot%s" % id(self))
        w1 = AWidget(None,**argv)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(w1)
        editor = argv.get('editor')
        editor.request_connect(self,INITF.name,False,self.initFirstTime)

    def initFirstTime(self, msg):
        print  "ShotInfoMain:",msg

################################################################
class BrowserApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent, **argv):

        super(BrowserApp, self).__init__(parent)
        editor = argv.get('editor')
        self.setObjectName("Browsert%s" % id(self))
        ll = ShotInfoMain(None,**argv)
        self.setCentralWidget(ll)
        editor.request_connect(self, INITF.name, True)
        msg = Msg(id(self))
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL(INITF.signature), msg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create a hub to where signal are send first
    ed = BaseEditor()
    # app
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # the mainwindow
    window = BrowserApp(None,editor=ed)

    # start
    QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
    window.show()
    window.raise_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Signals and slots in QMetaObject are not ordered correctly, this may lead to issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47777007/signals-and-slots-in-qmetaobject-are-not-ordered-correctly-this-may-lead-to-iss)

Comment: possible. But that one got removed :/